# Filtering based on the first 3 letters of a name

Tags: sql

Hi I am trying to filter a data from a column called "Name" and the data in that column could be HRC_1024, GRG_2314, FRR_2314, etc. I am trying to extract data where the first 3 characters end in 'G'. Based on that philosophy I should get only GRG_2314 or other data that has 'XXG_XXXX'.

I am not sure what functions that I could use but if there was one, it would be useful to know.

Comment: use substring on char 3 being g or just like ?

Comment: WHERE Name like <the third character on this string ends with 'G'>

Answer (score 0):

Just check the 3rd character; every database has a *substring* or similarly named string function

```
where substring(Name, 3, 1) = 'G';
```

Comment: --Thanks but I think I sort of figured it out 
Name LIKE '__G%' 
--Although what you have should work :)

Comment: There are numerous ways to skin this particular cat, although I do like cats.